# Cluster and limit points of $z$-ultrafilters

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a subspace of $Y$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a $z$-filter of $X$. We say that $y\in Y$ is a *cluster point* of $\mathcal{F}$ if $y\in\overline{Z}$ for every $Z\in \mathcal{F}$ (note that this closure is taken in $Y$). And $y$ is a *limit point* of $\mathcal{F}$ if every open set $V$ in $Y$ with $y\in V$ contains an element of $\mathcal{F}$ (we write $\mathcal{F}\to y$).

> Suppose $X$ is dense in $Y$.
>
> a) If $\mathcal{F}$ is a $z$-ultrafilter of $X$ and $y$ is a cluster point of $\mathcal{F}$, then $\mathcal{F}\to y$.
>
> b) For every $y$ there exists a $z$-ultrafilter $\mathcal{F}$ such that $\mathcal{F}\to y$.

This is what I have tried.

a) Suppose that $y\in\overline{Z}$ for every $Z\in\mathcal{F}$. I want to define some $z$-filter of $X$ that contains $\mathcal{F}$ (by giving some $z$-filterbase). Something like the family of $Z\cap V$ ($\neq\emptyset$) with $Z\in\mathcal{F}$ and $V$ neighborhood of $Y$. But are they zero sets of $X$? How do we use $X$ is dense in $Y$?

b) Because of a), we only need to care about $y$ being a cluster point of some $z$-ultrafilter. The most obvious thing I could think was:

$$\mathcal{F}:=\{Z\in\mathcal{Z}(X):y\in\overline{Z}\},$$

where $\mathcal{Z}(X)$ are the zero sets of $X$. But I couldn't prove it is closed under finite intersections; I mean, if $Z_1,Z_2\in\mathcal{F}$, would it be true $y\in\overline{Z_1\cap Z_2}$? (I don't think so...)

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m assuming that $Y$ is Tikhonov, the usual context for $z$-filters.

For (a) let $\mathscr{F}$ be a $z$-ultrafilter on $X$ that clusters at $y\in Y$, so that $y\in\bigcap_{F\in\mathscr{F}}\operatorname{cl}_YF$. Let $U$ be any open nbhd of $y$ in $Y$. Since $Y$ is Tikhonov, there is $Z\in\mathscr{Z}(Y)$ such that $y\in\mathscr{int}_YZ\subseteq Z\subseteq U$. $X$ is dense in $Y$, and $Z$ has non-empty interior in $Y$, so $Z\cap X\ne\varnothing$. Clearly $Z\cap X\in\mathscr{Z}(X)$. Now just verify that $Z\cap X$ meets every member of $\mathscr{F}$ and therefore must belong to $\mathscr{F}$.

In (b) you’re right that you can’t simply take $\mathscr{F}$ to be $\{Z\in\mathscr{Z}(X):y\in\operatorname{cl}_YZ\}$. Suppose, for instance, that $Y=\Bbb R$, $X$ is the subspace of irrationals, and $y=0$. The sets $[0,1]\cap X$ and $[-1,0]\cap X$ are $z$-sets in $X$, and $0$ is in their closures in $Y$, but their intersection is empty.

Start with $\mathscr{G}=\{Z\in\mathscr{Z}(Y):y\in\operatorname{int}_YZ\}$; this is a $z$-filter on $Y$ that converges to $y$. Now let $\mathscr{F}=\{G\cap X:G\in\mathscr{G}\}$.

Comment: Thank you, Brian. There's something I didn't know. Are saying that $\mathscr{Z}(Y)$ is a nbhd basis of $Y$? How you prove that? We can find a continuous function $f:Y\to [0,1]$ with $f(y)=0$ and $f(Y\setminus U)=\{1\}$. Maybe $Z=f^{-1}(0)$ would work I think, because $y\in Z$ and $Z\subseteq U$, but how to prove $y\in \mathscr{int}_YZ$? Thank you again.

Comment: @JonSK: Use $$Z=f^{-1}\left[\left[0,\frac12\right]\right]\;,$$ not $f^{-1}[\{0\}]$; this is still a $z$-set, and it has $y$ in its interior.

Comment: By $z$-set you mean zero set? Is it possible to find a continuous function $g$ on $Y$ such that $g^{-1}(0)=f^{-1}([0,1/2])$?

Comment: @JonSK: Yes to both. Let $$h:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto\begin{cases}0,&\text{if }x\le \frac12\\x-\frac12,&\text{if }x\ge\frac12 \end{cases}\;,$$ and let $g=h\circ f$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you very much, Brian.

Comment: @JonSK: You’re very welcome.